# IOS-Charts not removing old dataset values when I try to replace the dataset

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-charts

When I try to update the data with a fresh set of data, instead of showing the new data, the chart shows a concatenation of the new data and old data.  I tried calling `clear` and `clearValues` as well as `notifyDataSetChanged`
For example, if I call my update function with the same data repeatedly, I get the following effect:

**before**
[image]

**after**
[image]

From NSlogs, I see that the valueCount property keeps increasing by n values (n is number of original points) each time, but the number of dataSets is always 1.

Below is how I set the data for a BarChart

```
 NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [data count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *d = data[i];
        NSString *name = [d objectForKey:@"label"];
        int val = [[d objectForKey:@"num"] intValue];

        [yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:val xIndex:i]];
        [xVals addObject:name];

    }

    BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@"Occurences"];
    set1.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful;
    set1.drawValuesEnabled = YES;

    NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dataSets addObject:set1];
    BarChartData *bdata = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets];
    [bdata setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.f]];
    [_occuranceChart clear];
    [_occuranceChart clearValues];
    _occuranceChart.data = bdata;
    [_occuranceChart notifyDataSetChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

how do you update your data or data sets? clearly old data is not removed and you append new ones.

There are data entries, data sets, and data at 3 levels. If you don't want old data, you should call `removeDataSet`/`removeEntry` first and add your new ones by `addEntry`/`addEntryOrdered`/`addDataSet`.

If you don't want this way, you can easily assemble a new chartData and directly assign it to chartView.data. You don't have to manually call `chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()`, because data's setter will call it. But you should call it if you just add/remove data entries or sets.

Comment: I'm calling the same function to set the initial data and update. The charts are in storyboard, so I want to avoid creating a new chart each time.

I tried calling         `[_occuranceChart.data removeDataSetByIndex:0]` but nothing changed

Comment: if you are merely creating a new chart data like your posted code and assign it to chart view, it should be fine. I do such things a lot and never met this. You should post more code.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem.  It was unrelated -- the data I was passing in had the old entries

Comment: not going to add to the conversation but i have the same issue and as @Mahir i forget to clean my var (it just append the new data :D )

Comment: @ Mahir did you fix this issue. I am facing same issue. Plz share solution if you have. Thanks